# Question about 2^mersenne number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We are given that $2^n \equiv 2\ \pmod n $. If $m=2^n -1$, prove that $2^m \equiv 2\ \pmod m$

My first instinct is that we can somehow use fact that $2^n\equiv 1 \ \pmod m$ and use that, but I havent made any progress. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want to prove that $2^{m-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. Or that ;)

Comment: sorry it was $2^m\equiv2$

Comment: Which is equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend tackling the equivalent $2^{m-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

$$2^{m-1} = 2^{(2^n-1)-1} = 2^{2^n-2},$$

and now you may be able to see something.

Comment: thank you! this is helpful